# Java- getting wrong output

Tags: java

Here's my code that I've written :

```
public String binary(String s)
{
    String[] a = {
      "0000","0001","0010","0011","0100","0101","0110","0111",
      "1000","1001","1010","1011","1100","1101","1110","1111"
    };

    String k = "";
    for(int i = 0; i <= s.length() - 1; i++)
    {
        if      (s.charAt(i) == 'a') { k += a[10]; }
        else if (s.charAt(i) == 'b') { k += a[11]; }
        else if (s.charAt(i) == 'c') { k += a[12]; }
        else if (s.charAt(i) == 'd') { k += a[13]; }
        else if (s.charAt(i) == 'e') { k += a[14]; }
        else if (s.charAt(i) == 'f') { k += a[15]; }
        else { k += a[i]; }
    }
    return k;
}
```

I am getting output as a[0-9] = 0000. How can I fix this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share a sample input and the result you're trying to get for it?

Comment: HexaDecimal a=new HexaDecimal();
 System.out.println(a.binary("8"));    output is:0000

Comment: Your code is not case sensitive

Comment: Well, just off the top of my head, your code doesn't uppercase letters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `k+=a[i];` with `k+=a[s.charAt(i) - '0'];`

You're using your string index loop variable as an index into `a` rather than the character at that location in the string.

You need to do `- '0'` to convert from unicode codepoint to the value it represents as an ASCII digit (which I assume you want to use here)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and it worked!!Im new so i don't know that much

Comment: If this answer helps you then you should accept this answer and upvote it. _Accepting answer_ will reflect other users that problem is solved by this answer. It will also help other SO contributors  to focus on other unanswered questions. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with use of `a[i]`. It is a *logical error*. **Because** `i` is loop variable which indicates the current index in `s` `String`. But you are using it to indexing it in variable `a`. So, `i` variable is use incorrectly here.

Following is corrected (and a bit optimized) code. See it working [here](https://ideone.com/v64KHK):

```
public class HexaDecimal 
{
    public String binary(String s)
    {
        String[] a= {"0000","0001","0010","0011","0100","0101","0110","0111","1000","1001","1010","1011","1100","1101","1110","1111"};
        String k="";
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
        {
            char ch = Character.toUpperCase(s.charAt(i));
            if(ch>='A' && ch <= 'F') k+= a[ch - 'A' + 10];
            else k+= a[ch - '0'];
        }
        return k;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last else does the incorrect calculation. It does not take into consideration what is inputted, only the position. You want it to be

```
else { 
    k += a[s.charAt(i) - '0'];
}
```

There are easier ways to get the binary representation of hexadecimals, and you probably also want to check the input that it does not contain anything else than 0-9 or a-f.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the for loop to this:

```
for(int i=0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') k += a[c - '0'];
    else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') k += a[c - 'a' + 10];
    else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') k += a[c - 'A' + 10];
    else throw new InvalidArgumentException(s);
}
```

This is a lot simpler and self-explanatory, at least in my opinion. Handles digits, uppercase and lowercase letters, and fails in an expected way on bad input.